# Sublime Text - Change Color of called function

Tags: colors, sublimetext3

I want to change the color of a function I call from an object from white to something else.

[image: What I have so far]

I have changed almost all of the colors, but I can't find the name of this one.
Currently I have the newest version of Sublime

Comment: What langauge are you using? Also, please [edit] your question and post some real code, showing exactly what you want highlighted and what you don't.

Comment: Everything is said above. There is no language for settings in Sublime. Well not beside the given XML-File for the settings. There is no code because I dont need code for it. I'm asking if someone knows the attribute for the color of functions for an objects function

Comment: You didn't understand me. What programming language will you be using that includes the code you show above? JavaScript? PHP? Perl? I ask because different syntax definitions in Sublime use different scope names, so we can't help you unless you tell us what language you're using. I'm not talking about showing the markup in the `.tmTheme` file. We need some example programming code in the programming language you'll be using that has the construct above in it. You should also include some similar code if possible where the above syntax is *not* used, so we can differentiate between the two.

Comment: Oh that was what you mean. Sorry, I didn't understand indeed. My question is for PHP-Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I assume is php. You need to edit desired theme and add this code OR to edit "meta.function-call.object.php" key.

> function ***get_template_with_data***($type, $data)

```
<dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>Function Call</string>
      <key>scope</key>
      <string>meta.function-call</string>
      <key>settings</key>
      <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#0000FF</string>
      </dict>
</dict>
```

for this kind of function call:

> $this->email->***message***($message);

```
<dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Function name</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>variable.function</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>fontStyle</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#0000FF</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any reference to find all the things?